# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence- python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, valueerror

I am using python-3.x, and I am trying to run this cod but I received this error:

```
Z = np.fromiter(map(schwefel, zip(X.flat,Y.flat)), dtype=np.float16, 
count=X.shape[0]*X.shape[1]).reshape(X.shape)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I thank the problem is all bout float dtype which I couldn't solve it, please any suggestion or advice will be appreciated.

```
import random
from math import sin, cos, pi, exp, e, sqrt
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

try:
    import numpy as np
except:
    exit()

def schwefel(individual):
    N = len(individual)

    return 418.9828872724339*N-sum(x*sin(sqrt(abs(x))) for x in individual),

fig = plt.figure()
# ax = Axes3D(fig, azim = -29, elev = 50)
ax = Axes3D(fig)
X = np.arange(-500, 500, 10)
Y = np.arange(-500, 500, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)

Z = np.fromiter(map(schwefel, zip(X.flat,Y.flat)), dtype=np.float16, count=X.shape[0]*X.shape[1]).reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.show()
```

Comment: In Py3, `map` is a kind of generator, you need to wrap it in `list(map...)` to get a list.

Comment: Why aren't you performing the `schwefel` calculation with `numpy` functions?  (`np.sin`, `np.abs`, etc)

Comment: do you mean adding list to the code: `code(Z = np.fromiter (list(map(schwefel, zip(X.flat,Y.flat))))` @hpaulj if yes it doesn't work!!

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense!  Gives more information about the error and intermediate values.  You don't expect me to copy-n-paste the code to my computer and debug it myself, or do you?

Comment: What I did is `code Z = np.fromiter (list(map(schwefel, zip(X.flat,Y.flat)), dtype=np.float, count=X.shape[0]*X.shape[1])).reshape(X.shape)` but I receved this error `code TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)` !!! @hpaulj

Comment: You wrapped all the arguments to `fromiter` in your list, not just the `map`.  But once you get that working, look at the resulting list.  `fromiter` only works with a flat list.  Why are you using `fromiter` instead of `np.array`?

Comment: Fromiter because it is a resource-lazy way to build np.array objects @hpaulj

Comment: Here it isn't any faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
something = map(schwefel, zip(X.flat,Y.flat))
print(type(something))
something = list(something)
print(type(something), len(something))
print(something[:4])
Z = np.array(something)
print(Z.dtype, Z.shape)
```

produces

```
1010:~/mypy$ python3 stack43822778.py 
<class 'map'>
<class 'list'> 10000
[(476.78745748208433,), (586.67470048215569,), (696.81033496376426,), (801.49930810497494,)]
float64 (10000, 1)
```

The map produces a list of tuples.  `np.array` can handle that.  `np.fromiter` cannot.

```
def foo(X,Y):
    N = 2
    temp = X * np.sin(np.sqrt(np.abs(X))) + Y * np.sin(np.sqrt(np.abs(Y)))
    return 418.9828872724339*N - temp
```

and add

```
Z1 = foo(X,Y)
print(Z1.dtype, Z1.shape)
print(np.allclose(Z1, Z.reshape(100,100)))   # true
```

`foo` evaluates the function for all values of `X` and `Y` without any iteration.

---

If I simply omit a trailing comma, the `fromiter` approach works

```
return 418.9828872724339*N-sum(x*sin(sqrt(abs(x))) for x in individual) # ,

Z = np.fromiter(something, dtype=np.float16, count=X.shape[0]*X.shape[1]).reshape(X.shape)
print(Z.shape, Z.dtype)
```

`something[:4]` prints as:

```
[476.78745748208433, 586.67470048215569, 696.81033496376426, 801.49930810497494]
```

With the trailing comma, `schwefel` returns a 1 element tuple, not a scalar.

---

Testing the use of `np.fromiter`

Make a list of 10000 floats, and compare `np.array` with `np.fromiter`

```
In [55]: arr = np.random.rand(100,100)
In [56]: alist = arr.ravel().tolist()
In [57]: len(alist)
Out[57]: 10000
In [58]: timeit np.fromiter(alist, dtype=np.float16, count=10000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 550 µs per loop
In [59]: timeit np.array(alist, np.float16)
1000 loops, best of 3: 506 µs per loop
In [60]: timeit np.array(alist)
1000 loops, best of 3: 412 µs per loop
In [61]: timeit np.array(alist, np.float64)
1000 loops, best of 3: 413 µs per loop
```

Basically the same time.